# Bad request Android retrofit sending jsonArray

Tags: android, arrays, retrofit

I'm trying to communicate with a service that needs to receive a json array as following:

```
[{
"PAR_IND_COD_AREA_PROC": "1",
"PAR_COD_AREA_PROC": "H",
"PAR_IND_EQPMT_DESTINO": "0",
"PAR_EQPMT_DESTINO": "",
"PAR_IND_COD_EQPMT_PRODC": "1",
"PAR_COD_EQPMT_PRODC": "DBQ",
"PAR_IDENT_UNMET": "",
"PAR_COD_TIPO_ACO": "",
"PAR_COD_GRUPO_ACO": "",
"PAR_DTH_INI_PRAZO": "",
"PAR_DTH_FIM_PRAZO": "",
"PAR_COD_INTER_PEDCL": "",
"PAR_COD_ITEM_PEDCL": "",
"PAR_COD_CLIENTE": "",
"PAR_NUM_CAMPA_RB": "",
"PAR_UM_PROXI": ""
}, true]
```

and for doing so, I'm using retrofit with the following method:

```
@POST(Constants.MOVIMENTAR_BUSCA)
Call<RetornoCompletoBuscaUmsMovimentar> getBuscaMovimentarUms(@Body JSONStringer data);
```

the okHttpLogger that I'm using is telling me that what I'm sending to the server is:

```
D/OkHttp: {"out":"[{\"PAR_IND_COD_AREA_PROC\":\"1\",\"PAR_COD_AREA_PROC\":\"H\",\"PAR_IND_EQPMT_DESTINO\":\"0\",\"PAR_EQPMT_DESTINO\":\"\",\"PAR_IND_COD_EQPMT_PRODC\":\"1\",\"PAR_COD_EQPMT_PRODC\":\"DBQ\",\"PAR_IDENT_UNMET\":\"\",\"PAR_COD_TIPO_ACO\":\"\",\"PAR_COD_GRUPO_ACO\":\"\",\"PAR_DTH_INI_PRAZO\":\"\",\"PAR_DTH_FIM_PRAZO\":\"\",\"PAR_COD_INTER_PEDCL\":\"\",\"PAR_COD_ITEM_PEDCL\":\"\",\"PAR_COD_CLIENTE\":\"\",\"PAR_NUM_CAMPA_RB\":\"\",\"PAR_UM_PROXI\":\"\"},true]","stack":[]}
```

the jsonStringer is being build like this:

```
private JSONStringer jsonStringToSend(String PAR_IND_COD_AREA_PROC,
String PAR_COD_AREA_PROC, String PAR_IND_EQPMT_DESTINO,
String PAR_EQPMT_DESTINO, String PAR_IND_COD_EQPMT_PRODC,
String PAR_COD_EQPMT_PRODC, String PAR_IDENT_UNMET,
String PAR_COD_TIPO_ACO, String PAR_COD_GRUPO_ACO,
String PAR_DTH_INI_PRAZO, String PAR_DTH_FIM_PRAZO,
String PAR_COD_INTER_PEDCL, String PAR_COD_ITEM_PEDCL,
String PAR_COD_CLIENTE, String PAR_NUM_CAMPA_RB,
String PAR_UM_PROXI){
try {
return new JSONStringer().array()
.object().key("PAR_IND_COD_AREA_PROC").value(PAR_IND_COD_AREA_PROC)
.key("PAR_COD_AREA_PROC").value(PAR_COD_AREA_PROC)
.key("PAR_IND_EQPMT_DESTINO").value(PAR_IND_EQPMT_DESTINO)
.key("PAR_EQPMT_DESTINO").value(PAR_EQPMT_DESTINO)
.key("PAR_IND_COD_EQPMT_PRODC").value(PAR_IND_COD_EQPMT_PRODC)
.key("PAR_COD_EQPMT_PRODC").value(PAR_COD_EQPMT_PRODC)
.key("PAR_IDENT_UNMET").value(PAR_IDENT_UNMET)
.key("PAR_COD_TIPO_ACO").value(PAR_COD_TIPO_ACO)
.key("PAR_COD_GRUPO_ACO").value(PAR_COD_GRUPO_ACO)
.key("PAR_DTH_INI_PRAZO").value(PAR_DTH_INI_PRAZO)
.key("PAR_DTH_FIM_PRAZO").value(PAR_DTH_FIM_PRAZO)
.key("PAR_COD_INTER_PEDCL").value(PAR_COD_INTER_PEDCL)
.key("PAR_COD_ITEM_PEDCL").value(PAR_COD_ITEM_PEDCL)
.key("PAR_COD_CLIENTE").value(PAR_COD_CLIENTE)
.key("PAR_NUM_CAMPA_RB").value(PAR_NUM_CAMPA_RB)
.key("PAR_UM_PROXI").value(PAR_UM_PROXI).endObject()
.value(true).endArray();
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been using retrofit for JSONObjects POST for long now, but can't seem to figure out this particular case with JSONArray

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your logcat for any kind of exception

Comment: unfortunately there's none, only the response:
"400 Bad Request" {Message : The request is Invalid}

Comment: can you log your json created by jsonStringToSend i think there is some problem with json that you are creating

Comment: [{"PAR_IND_COD_AREA_PROC":"1","PAR_COD_AREA_PROC":"H","PAR_IND_EQPMT_DESTINO":"0","PAR_EQPMT_DESTINO":"","PAR_IND_COD_EQPMT_PRODC":"1","PAR_COD_EQPMT_PRODC":"DBQ","PAR_IDENT_UNMET":"","PAR_COD_TIPO_ACO":"","PAR_COD_GRUPO_ACO":"","PAR_DTH_INI_PRAZO":"","PAR_DTH_FIM_PRAZO":"","PAR_COD_INTER_PEDCL":"","PAR_COD_ITEM_PEDCL":"","PAR_COD_CLIENTE":"","PAR_NUM_CAMPA_RB":"","PAR_UM_PROXI":""},true]

The problem isn't with the json unfortunately, I've checked it on PostMan and receive the 200 code with expected response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day of research, I've found this [answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202373/retrofit-como-enviar-um-json-via-post) on the portuguese version of stackoverflow that solved my problem. No need for translation, the code is self explanatory!